# How to show the months in array in a dropdown using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[Firestrore Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeKUR.png)

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
           
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(uid)
                .collection('transactions')
                .doc(monthCode)
                .collection('details')
                .orderBy('date')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();

              if (setDefaultMake) {
                year = snapshot.data!.docs[0].get('date');

                debugPrint('setDefault make: $year');
              }
              return DropdownButton(
                dropdownColor: Colors.blue[700],
                isExpanded: false,
                value: year,
                items: snapshot.data!.docs.map((value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: value.get('date'),
                    child: Text(
                      '${value.get('date')}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  debugPrint('selected onchange: $value');
                  setState(
                    () {
                      debugPrint('make selected: $value');
                      // Selected value will be stored
                      year = value;
                      // Default dropdown value won't be displayed anymore
                      setDefaultMake = false;
                      // Set makeModel to true to display first car from list
                      setDefaultMakeModel = true;
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
```

users/uid/transactions/20223/details/monthlydetails -> Schema in firestore for where date is stored as field

How to show the months in array in a dropdown using flutter? Thanks in advance.

users/uid/transactions/20223/details/monthlydetails -> Schema in firestore for where date is stored as field

How to show the months in array in a dropdown using flutter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some code snippets of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana Please have a look. I basically want to show all the documentids in the dropdown.